# Как в Firefox открывать ссылки результатов поиска в новой вкладке?

Tags: firefox

У меня Firefox 57. Если установить поисковую систему 'Google' в браузере и нажать на одну из ссылок из результата поиска, то ссылка открывается в той же вкладке, это дико неудобно. Если установить поисковую систему 'Яндекс' или 'Mail.ru' или 'DuckDuckGo' то ссылки открываются в новой вкладке, именно так мне и нужно. Но как быть с "Google" ?

Comment: Для открытия ссылок в новых вкладках давным-давно используется нажатие на колесико мыши или удержание CTRL при клике по ссылке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы ссылки из результатов поиска в поисковике Google открывались на новой странице/вкладке, нужно перейти на [страницу настроек](https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en&pli=1) и отметить галочкой следующий пункт:

> «Where results open» -> «Open each selected result in a new browser window«.

Страница настроек на русском языке. Там нужно поставить галочку напротив

> Открывать результаты -> В новом окне

Answer (score 0):

Кроме настроек поиска открыть расширенные настройки firexox (about:config) и установить параметр browser.link.open_newwindow = 3